# Linear gradient aliasing with CoreGraphics

Tags: core-graphics

I'm trying to emulate the color tint effect from the `UITabBarItem`.

When I draw a linear gradient at an angle, I get visible aliasing in the middle part of the gradient where the two colors meet at the same location. Left is `UITabBarItem`, right is my gradient with visible aliasing (stepping):

[image: gradient aliasing]

Here is the snippet of relevant code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(c);
CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0, -1.0);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();  
CGFloat components[16] = {1,1,1,1, 
                          109.0/255.0,175.0/255.0,246.0/255.0,1, 
                          31.0/255.0,133.0/255.0,242.0/255.0,1, 
                          143.0/255.0,194.0/255.0,248.0/255.0,1};
CGFloat locations[4] = {0.0, 0.62, 0.62, 1};
CGGradientRef colorGradient = 
      CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, components, 
                                          locations, (size_t)4);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, colorGradient, CGPointZero,
                            CGPointMake(size.width*1.0/3.9, -size.height),0);
CGGradientRelease(colorGradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRestoreGState(c);

UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return resultImage;
```

What do I need to change, to get a smooth angled gradient like in UITabBarItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a current workaround, I draw the gradient at double resolution into an image and then draw the image with original dimensions. The image scaling that occurs, takes care of the aliasing. At the pixel level the result is not as smooth as in the `UITabBarItem`, but that probably uses an image created in Photoshop or something similar.

Comment: As there are no other ideas in 10 days, in spite of using bounty on this question, I'm accepting my own solution. :-|

Answer (score 1):

What is the interpolation quality of your context set to? CGContextGetInterpolationQuality()/CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(). Try changing that if it's too low.

If that doesn't work, I'm curious what happens if you draw the gradient vertically (0,Ymin)-(0,Ymax) but apply a rotation transformation to your context...